# Adding registration to home page using yii framework

Tags: php, yii, registration

We are trying to add a new user registration to our home page for our yii application. We have successfully made a separate registration page that connects to a mysql database, we are now trying to add this functionality to index.php instead of a separate register.php in views.

We tried to change actionIndex() in SiteController to send a register form:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $registerForm = new RegisterForm();
    $this->render('index', array('registerForm'=>$registerForm));
}
```

We're getting an error from our index.php: "Undefined variable: registerForm"
Here is the relevant code from index.php:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'action' => array('site/register'),
'id'=>'registration-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    )); ?>

<?php echo $form->textField($registerForm,'username'); ?>

<?php echo $form->passwordField($registerForm,'password'); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register'); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it second code in /views/site/index.php ?

Comment: yeah, is that code actually inside index.php, or is it in another file that's rendered in index.php?

Comment: It's actually in /views/site/index.php